# Warning : "org.apache.struts.util.PropertyMessageResources Resource org/apache/struts/taglib/LocalStrings_en.properties Not Found." in Struts 2.3.32

Tags: struts2

I migrated a application from Struts 2.1 to 2.3.x. I now find warnings on my log stating "Resource org/apache/struts/taglib/LocalStrings_en.properties Not Found." . I did some reading and it does sound benign. However, since I never had internationalized property files, I am not sure why I get these messages now. Any ideas?

Comment: It is only a warning, right? Unrelated, you should use 2.3.34.

Comment: It is a warning only. I was just puzzled that it was thrown in the 2.3 version only and not before. I was not able to find any internationalization related difference specifically between the 2.

Comment: Are you using S1 too in that app?

Comment: In the larger application, yes. I am using S1 in a different part of the application.

Comment: The warning comes from there.